# Ping with a variable in linux script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I want that my script pings the ip-addresses
192.168.0.45
192.168.0.17
192.168.0.108
by doing this:

```
bash Script.sh 45 17 108
```

I want to give the last numbers with bash to ping this ip-addresses.

I don't know how I have to do this. Do I have to work with a 'case' in a do while or something else??

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $*; do
  ping 192.168.0.$i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to give the last numbers with bash to ping this ip-addresses.

I presume, you want to ping the addresses simultaneously. In that case you can do this:

**Script.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
ping 192.168.0.$1 & ping 192.168.0.$2 & ping 192.168.0.$3 &
```

This will send all of the three ping commands to background where they will be executed simultaneously and print continuous output on terminal.

You can do this with a for loop too:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $*;do
ping 192.168.0.$i &
done
```

The for loop method can take any number of arguments